# Adding a number to column [line by line]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a text file named `text`: The row and columns are:

```
1   A   18  -180
2   B   19  -180
3   C   20  -150
50  D   21  -100
128 E   22  -130
10  F   23  -0
10  G   23  -0
```

What I want to do is to print out the 4th column with adding a constant number to each of the lines (except `==0`). To do this is what I have done.

```
 #!/bin/bash

FILE="/dir/text"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done <"$FILE"
```

I can read the fourth column, but at the same time I want to put an argument `$1` which will add a constant number to all of the lines in the fourth column except any line of the fourth column has `==0`.

UPDATE:

The Desired output would be like: [the line has zeros are ignored]

```
-160
-160
-130
-80
-110
```

For example, the program name is `example.sh`. I want to add a number to the fourth column using an argument. Therefore it would be:

example.sh $1

where $1 could be any number I want to add in the 4th column.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Don't use a shell loop for this, it's completely the wrong approach. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the issues. Also you say `the line has zeros are ignored` but they aren't they're deleted, right? And you only want the 4th field output, not the whole line, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
while read -ra a; do [[ ${a[3]} != -0 ]] && ((a[3]+=42)); echo "${a[@]}"; done < file
```

Output:

```
1 A 18 -138
2 B 19 -138
3 C 20 -108
50 D 21 -58
128 E 22 -88
10 F 23 -0
10 G 23 -0
```

Answer (score 6):

You should `awk` here which will be faster than bash.

```
awk -v number="100" '$4!=0{$4+=number} 1' Input_file
```

`number` is an `awk` variable where you could set its value as per your need.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v number="100" '   ##Starting awk program from here and creating a variable number whose value is 100.
$4!=0{                  ##Checking condition if 4th column is NOT zero then do following.
  $4+=number            ##Adding variable number to 4th column here.
}
1                       ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines.
' Input_file            ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to preserve your formatting using `awk` while adding the values to the 4th field, you can calculate the new value of the 4th field and then use `sub` to change the value without forcing `awk` to recalculate the fields and removing the whitespace.

For example, with your file stored as `text` and adding a value of `180` to the 4th field (except where `0`), you could do:

```
awk -v n=180 '$4!=0 {newval=$4+n; sub(/[0-9]+$/,newval)}1' text
```

Doing so would produce the following output:

```
$ awk -v n=180 '$4!=0 {newval=$4+n; sub(/[0-9]+$/,newval)}1' text
1   A   18  0
2   B   19  0
3   C   20  30
50  D   21  80
128 E   22  50
10  F   23  -0
10  G   23  -0
```

If called withing a shell script, you could pass your `$1` parameter as:

```
awk -v n="$1" '$4!=0 {newval=$4+n; sub(/[0-9]+$/,newval)}1' text
```

Though I would suggest checking that an argument has been provided to the script with:

```
[ -z "$1" ] && {
    echo "error: value require as argument"
    exit 1
}
```

or you can provide a default value -- up to you.